# OpenGL textured cube tutorial - example code not working

Tags: opengl

I've been going through the opengl tutorials here: 
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

The site provides you with completed versions of each tutorial so you can compare with your own implementation.  Unfortunately tutorial 5 doesn't appear to work for me (neither my implementation nor the provided one).  I've attached pictures of what I believe it should look like and what I get when I run the executable generated from their code.

I'm using a 2015 MacBook Pro running Windows 10, compiling in VS2015, using Intel's Iris 6100 integrated GPU.

[image: what I think the right output is]

[image: my output]

The following code is from the tutorial.

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include <common/shader.hpp>
#include <common/texture.hpp>

int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 05 - Textured Cube", NULL, NULL);
if( window == NULL ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

// Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

// Enable depth test
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
// Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); 

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "TransformVertexShader.vertexshader", "TextureFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );

// Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");

// Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
// Camera matrix
glm::mat4 View       = glm::lookAt(
                            glm::vec3(4,3,3), // Camera is at (4,3,3), in World Space
                            glm::vec3(0,0,0), // and looks at the origin
                            glm::vec3(0,1,0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
                       );
// Model matrix : an identity matrix (model will be at the origin)
glm::mat4 Model      = glm::mat4(1.0f);
// Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
glm::mat4 MVP        = Projection * View * Model; // Remember, matrix multiplication is the other way around

// Load the texture using any two methods
//GLuint Texture = loadBMP_custom("uvtemplate.bmp");
GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvtemplate.DDS");

// Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");

// Our vertices. Tree consecutive floats give a 3D vertex; Three consecutive vertices give a triangle.
// A cube has 6 faces with 2 triangles each, so this makes 6*2=12 triangles, and 12*3 vertices
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
};

// Two UV coordinatesfor each vertex. They were created withe Blender.
static const GLfloat g_uv_buffer_data[] = { 
    0.000059f, 1.0f-0.000004f, 
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f, 
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f, 
    1.000023f, 1.0f-0.000013f, 
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f, 
    0.999958f, 1.0f-0.336064f, 
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f, 
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f, 
    0.667969f, 1.0f-0.671889f, 
    1.000023f, 1.0f-0.000013f, 
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f, 
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f, 
    0.000059f, 1.0f-0.000004f, 
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f, 
    0.336098f, 1.0f-0.000071f, 
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f, 
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f, 
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f, 
    1.000004f, 1.0f-0.671847f, 
    0.999958f, 1.0f-0.336064f, 
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f, 
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f, 
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f, 
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f, 
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f, 
    0.668104f, 1.0f-0.000013f, 
    0.336098f, 1.0f-0.000071f, 
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f, 
    0.000004f, 1.0f-0.671870f, 
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f, 
    0.000103f, 1.0f-0.336048f, 
    0.336024f, 1.0f-0.671877f, 
    0.335973f, 1.0f-0.335903f, 
    0.667969f, 1.0f-0.671889f, 
    1.000004f, 1.0f-0.671847f, 
    0.667979f, 1.0f-0.335851f
};

GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint uvbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_uv_buffer_data), g_uv_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

do{

    // Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
    // in the "MVP" uniform
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        2,                                // size : U+V => 2
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3); // 12*3 indices starting at 0 -> 12 triangles

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

// Cleanup VBO and shader
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glDeleteProgram(programID);
glDeleteTextures(1, &TextureID);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because you are **not inverting the y component of the UV-coords** (since DDS has a *different-D3D-based* coordinate system compared to OpenGL). You should either invert it in the **fragment shader** (as easy as `1.0f-uv.y`) or **inverting the image before compressing it**. Check out that tutorial (which is awesome, by the way). At the end, it talks about inversing the UVs:

> DXT compression comes from the DirectX world, where the V texture coordinate is inversed compared to OpenGL. So if you use compressed textures, you’ll have to use ( coord.u, 1.0-coord.v) to fetch the correct texel. You can do this whenever you want : in your export script, in your loader, in your shader...

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I thought I was already doing that when g_uv_buffer_data is initialized?  Could you please elaborate?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think so, I checked out my implementation of this and I did have those `1.0f` in `g_uv_buffer_data` AND `color = texture(textureSampler, vec2(UV.x, 1.0-UV.y)).rgb;` in my fragment shader.

Comment: I think he put those `1.0f` in `g_uv_buffer_data` simply to make the manual value inputs easier?

Comment: Your solution worked.  Thank you very much for your help.